Custom RHEL7 ISO Legacy Boot USB installation kickstart not automatically accepting installation media
I have a custom RHEL7.8 installation ISO which works exactly as expected when I burn it to a DVD and install using that disk (using Legacy Boot and not UEFI). Now I am trying to update this to support installation from USB and after much trial and error I have managed to get to the point where I can boot from the USB and perform the complete installation (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/787924/converting-cd-kickstart-file-to-usb for the full ordeal) except for one detail:
The process is not as fully automated as it should be - upon reaching the "main installation menu" it reports Error Setting Up Base Repository for the Installation Source.
At this point I have to go to the Installation Source submenu and select Done for the installation to proceed. The Installation Source displays and pre-selects the USB device as the Auto-Detected Installation Media and I don't need to do anything other than acknowledge the pre-selected option (at which point it re-verifies the selection as initially, though this time it succeeds).
Why is this? It appears that the USB media is automatically selected as the Installation Source, but on initial start is fails to resolve it?
For context my goal is to have any number of kickstart files on the disk, allowing a single disk to be used to perform the installation of a variety of different system configurations, with each kickstart performing one. The isolinux.cfg includes menu entries as follows:
label linux
  menu label Option 1
  menu default
  kernel vmlinuz
  append xdriver=vesa nomodeset initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL inst.repo=hd:LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL:/ inst.ks=hd:LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL:/config/opt1/anaconda-ks-option1.cfg

and in the kickstart file I specify the installation source:
repo --name="USB Media" --baseurl=file:///mnt/install/repo # Added for USB install, not sure if necessary
install
harddrive --partition=LABEL=MY_USB_LABEL --dir=/ # in lieu of cdrom for DVD installation

Thanks for any ideas, thoughts, or other feedback!
